# 42000 [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'go'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, select, pyodbc

I want to select data from my database using a python script. The connection is working fine, and the query is working when I am executing it in the `SQL server management system`, but doesn't work when I use `pyodbc`.

the query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [cities]
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

the `pyodbc` interpretation:

```py
def sqlexec(conn, query:str, print_:bool = False, return_ = False):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    answer = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
    if print_:
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
    conn.commit()
    if return_:
        return answer

cursor = sqlexec(conn,
                      '''use [law and order]
                        go
                        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [cities]
                        ORDER BY NEWID()''',
                        return_=True)
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```

`law and order` is the name of the database, and `cities` is the name of the table I am selecting random information from

Comment: `GO` is **not** a T-SQL operator; it's an IDE operator

Comment: Either set the database when you connect or select from `[law and order].dbo.[cities]`. Replace `dbo` with your schema.

Comment: all i needed to do is remove the ```use [law and order ] go``` part